# 外部 SMTP サーバを指定したメール送信に失敗する smtp-server: 554 Service unavailable

Tags: linux, mail

RHEL8 の mailx コマンドでのメール送信に失敗します。

/root/.mailrcに記述している内容は以下の通りです。

```
set smtp=smtp://<外部SMTPサーバIPアドレス>:25
set from=xxxxxx@xxxxxx.co.jp
```

25番ポートを使用しているため、
smtp-auth-user
smtp-auth-password
これらの記述は不要という認識で合っていますか。

また、メール送信エラー時には以下のようなエラーメッセージが表示されます。

```
smtp-server: 554 Service unavailable
"/root/dead.letter" 22/941
. . . message not sent.
```

ネットでエラーメッセージを調べてみたものの、具体的な解決策について触れられている記事はほとんどなく、困っています。

個人的に立てた仮説としましては、以下のことが挙げられます。

1. mailxコマンドを実行するサーバのIPアドレスが、外部SMTPサーバに到達した時点で弾かれている
2. set from=で指定した送信元アカウントが存在していない
3. やはりSMTP認証が必要

少ない情報ではありますが、いかが思われますでしょうか？

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

> 25番ポートを使用しているため、
> smtp-auth-user
> smtp-auth-password
> これらの記述は不要という認識で合っていますか。

SMTPサーバーによります。
あなたやあなたの組織が管理しているものでなければ、認証なしに無制限にリレーすることはしないと思います。